# Hashicorp Vault production hardening. 'Run bare metal' vs 'disable remote access'

Tags: security, hashicorp-vault

I'm currently playing with Hashicorp's Vault but this is probably a question with more general security implications.

I've been reading through the Production Hardening recommendations for Vault [here](https://www.vaultproject.io/guides/operations/production) for some pointers.

While the advice there makes perfect sense, taken individually, there were a couple of elements which seem to contradict. I'm not sure how I'd go about implementing it all in production.

The two points I'm struggling with are the suggestion to "Disable SSH / Remote Desktop" and that "running on bare metal should be preferred to a VM".

It seems to me that deploying an instance to a bare metal machine and subsequently disabling remote access (I'm assuming if we're ssh is discouraged then out of band management technologies like IPMI should also be off limits) effectively make the host unmanageable without physical access? Is this even achievable for cloud-based deployments?

Is my analysis correct or am I missing something? How do I choose which I should implement if I can't do both?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant do both at the same time, so your struggle is correct.

In an ideal world, you should be building images with vault and then use those to run your cluster. Then you can disable ssh/remote access so that the server running Vault is in a very well defined state (ie running the exact same thing as the image template and no-one has logged into it which could result in manual changes).

> How do I choose which I should implement if I can't do both?

If you are in the cloud, forget bare metals and go with the VMs. If you are not in the cloud and you can tailor your VM size, you could go with bare metal (for example our current server size is 128GB RAM which is a waste for just one Vault instance, and we need 3 of them for HA).